# Gaussian Integers how to solve with association

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, gaussian-integers

I have this problem following.

Two elements $a$ and $b$ of a commutative ring $\mathbb{R}$ with one are said to be associated if there is a unit $u$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $a = u \cdot b$

Find $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $87 + 13i$ and $13 + ai$ are associated in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

I thought this as set these equal:

$87+13i=u \cdot (13+ai)$ and i thought you could set u to i?
$87+13i=i \cdot (13+ai) \implies 13i-a = 87+13i$ do i thinking correct but the answers when i check them says $a=-87$ and $u=-i$ i'dont understand how to solve it?

Comment: To get from $13i$ to $13$, multiply by $-i$

Comment: J. W. Tanner How can you see that i need to multiply by -i?

Comment: As I indicated, because you want to multiply by a unit $(1, i, -1,$ or $-i)$ to get from $87+\color{blue}{13i}$ to $\color{blue}{13}+ai$

Comment: The associates of $87+13i$ are $87+13i, 87i-13, -87-13i,$ and $-87i+13$

Comment: J. W. Tanner How can it only be one unit in this case where u = -i ?

Comment: I don’t understand your last question

Comment: You got $a=-87$ using $u_1=i$, while the book got $a=-87$ using $u_2=-i$. Both are correct because $87+13i=i \cdot (13-87i)$ and $13-87i = -i(87+13i)$. The definition of associates allows you to swap the roles of $a$ and $b$ because you can divide both sides by the unit $u$ to get $b=u^{-1}\cdot a$ and $u^{-1}$ is still a unit.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis The problem is that my book says that only u=-i is the only solution i'don't understand?

Comment: Once you choose which of $87+13i$ and $13+ai$ goes on the left and which goes on the right in the equation in the definition of associates, there is only one value of $u$ that works. With one choice only $u=i$ works, with the other choice only $u=-i$ works. Both are valid choices. But the actual question is not asking for the value of $u$, only for the value of $a$.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis How can i see this is important to a ?